# Does anyone know what the UK tax code MI means?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom

Does anyone know what the UK tax code MI means. direct.gov.uk doesn't help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you see this? I would suspect that it is a simple mistake.

If you try to do a P14 online submission with a Taxcode of, for example, MI1234, it will be rejected as invalid.

Background, I am a programmer and I have had to write UK payroll software and have never come across such a code in any of the specifications and since the tax code controls how much tax you pay, they can't just make new codes without telling the software developers.

Comment: I'll accept this. I haven't had the opportunity to phone the HMRC... it's probably a mistake if no one knows about it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it "M1" after your normal tax code, rather than a bare "MI"? If so, it means that your tax is calculated on a month-by-month basis rather than taking into account your earnings and tax paid in the tax year up to this point.

Comment: No. It's defiantly a I rather than a 1. I can confirm this because the next digit is a 1. So I can see "MI1xxx".

Comment: And you're absolutely certain it's a tax code? The HMRC website doesn't admit the existence of such a beast either!